# Conditional type based on a non-empty string

Tags: typescript

There are TONS of questions about conditional types based on a value.
However I'm not sure can scenario below be implemented at all.

I'm getting acquainted with conditional types and I'm wondering if it's possible to make a conditional type that will be dependant on a non-empty string.

Let's consider next interface:

```
interface Animal {
    dogName: string;
    canBark: boolean;
}
```

and

```
interface AnimalToBeMapped {
    dogsNickname?: string;
    /// some other props
}
```

I'm using this interface to map an object

```
function mapAnimal(animal: AnimalToBeMapped): Animal {
    return {
        dogName: animal.dogsNickname,
        canBark: !animal.dogsNickname
    }
}
```

I'm setting `canBark` property to `true` only when the argument object has a `dogName` property set (should work also for empty string vs. non-empty string).

What I want to do is to add additional type-safety to my `Animal` interface (if someone is setting `dogName` manually to be defined then I want to force `canBark` property to be `true` and vise versa).

example:

```
const exmpl1: Animal = {
    dogName: 'Rex',
    canBark: false // I want an error here
}
```

and

```
const exmpl2: Animal = {
    dogName: '',
    canBark: true // An error here
}
```

Comment: Are you open for any workarounds? For instance, it is possible to make function which will accept two arguments (dogName and canBark)? Or type wirh generic argument?

Comment: Looks to me you are trying something that TypeScript was not designed for. TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, so any dynamic *runtime* behavior cannot be enforced with TypeScript typing features. The examples you provide contain hard-coded values and those will be checked just fine during compile time. But when I read something like "if someone is setting `dogName` manually to be defined then I want to force `canBark` property to be true and vise versa", I think about scenarios like handling user input or API fetch results. You're out of luck there. You need to write validation logic for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please let me know if it works for you

```js
type NonEmptyString<T extends string> = T extends '' ? never : T;

type WithName = {
  dogName: string,
  canBark: true,
}

type WithoutName = {
  dogName?: '',
  canBark: false
};

type Animal = WithName | WithoutName;


type Overloadings =
  & ((arg: { canBark: false }) => Animal)
  & ((arg: { dogName: '', canBark: false }) => Animal)
  & (<S extends string>(arg: { dogName: NonEmptyString<S>, canBark: true }) => Animal)

const animal: Overloadings = (arg: Animal) => {
  return arg

}

const x = animal({ dogName: '', canBark: false }) // ok
const xx = animal({ dogName: 'a', canBark: true }) // ok
const xxx = animal({ dogName: 'a', canBark: false }) // error
const xxxx = animal({ dogName: '', canBark: true }) // error
const xxxxx = animal({ canBark: true }) // error
const xxxxxx = animal({ canBark: false }) // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAOQPYDsCiBbKkDKYBOAligOYA8AKnDAB5gwoAmAznMwcSQHxwC8cVWvSasA5KLgB%20OChgA3GPjgAuAQG5QoSLDgB1QmAAWCAIYZ4-AN6g4cRkhKnzq9kVIAaG3ADGJlACETfABrVQIAVxhPEABfTXBoeH0jJHCwJws4axBbe0czGElVcWjbXwCg0LgAMxMAG2YYUBiNEC1EuABBFEIMer49A2MCuAAfQZS0jNb47XgAeQV8OqQTRk5WXi8AMjgACj2gklVLHz9AkNVahvgYgEo%20Hm7e%20rud-cP8Y6y7Bwzi0TuM4VS41eqNOD3R5dHp9OpvHJwXZ7Mg4ah0BgsNgcUhcT7fU55f6IVCYbAQPBucg4LhA8oXKoRW4PXhPWGveLeVDsOB%20F51VSLRQrNYbAb41TPOEsnjZWz4GBgcL4FC8r7xOJtEBclA8mgDPlwvaEv4FAF086VK7g5lwAD0drgSGCoB1ev1-EN9WNv3yzjgohMgOBDLC%20EikIeDqdLu13LAcBoSYN7LqPqJZoDQYtIKq1whUOjinwSHwrvjiaTHt5qfTpv9JRDVrgTMj9sdxdL5d1Caryc9tdO9ObrcLHfwJbLcZ7lb7Kf5PuHoPztujzviG5AQA)

It is not so easy for TS to find distinguish between empty string and string. Type `string` is assignable to literal type `''` (empty string), that's whu I used `NonEmptyString` helper

**UPDATE**
If you are interested in a bit simplier solution, which is not requires extra funxtion, see this example:

```js
type WithName = {
  dogName: string,
  canBark: true,
}

type WithoutName = {
  canBark: false
};

type Animal = WithName | WithoutName;

const x: Animal = {
  dogName: 'name',
  canBark: true
}; // ok

const xx:Animal={
  canBark:false
}; // ok

const xxx:Animal={
  canBark:true
} // expected error

const xxxx:Animal={
  dogName:''
} // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAdQJZgBYDkCGBbeBeOAb1DjgBMB7Acy1wC44BnMAJyQDsqAaEuAY0zsAQphYBrBqwCuMHiAC%20oUJFiIUqClLC18RXgOGiJcAGaYANoxih5AbiXho8AILsk2C3ALI0OuAB81NE1tHBh7EFA%20CnZmOAAPBld3TwJiEFJKGjCGAHJ2MNy5UgMRcUkWGRtbOAB6WrgKMQdo2LAExOSPczx0ksEyiTNLawUa%20sbmyJBWuPj5ui6LXv0BozppUfk6hph42D4wGDI4GBYWChYWmLn5zrdulYzyah06XNybHdP9mEPj07nS4OEHTIA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First of all, I would like to say that your answer is something next-levelish as usual! Awesome! However, after seeing this I’m thinking about simplifying this approach a bit… Do you think it can be done if instead of checking the property is non-empty string I will just make a property `dogName` optional? See we can just check if it exists then lock `canBark` to true. And if `dogName` does not exist `canBark` should be always false

Comment: @anotheruser, yes, you can stick with simple union. I made an update in my answer